# Scaffolding Controllers or Views using EntityFramework is not supported when using configSource in the Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

If I try to add a new `Web API 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework` I get the following message:

> Scaffolding Controllers or Views using EntityFramework is not
>   supported when using configSource in the Web.config

[image]

The only `configSource` I have in `Web.config` is for Unity.

```
<unity configSource="Unity.config" />
```

If I comment out this line I can use the method as intended. Is this related to Unity, DI or just `configSource`?

Comment: I guess this is EF6?

Comment: Which VS version you're using? I encountered similar issue when using `configSource` for some conditions, including `connectionStrings` or something else.

Comment: @GertArnold 6.1.3

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto `VS Enterprise 2017 15.5.3`

Comment: And what does "Learn more" tell you?

Comment: @GertArnold Link to "Introduction to ASP.NET Core" -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/

Comment: O yeah, those helpful links telling you exactly what to do with an exception message :(. Anyway, the message suggests that using configSource *anywhere* is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015 this gave a hard error and you had no idea where to look.

They 'fixed' the issue in VS2017 by adding this error message. There is no solution, other than to put your config data (in my case connectionstrings) directly into web.config, and not refer to an external file.

No other solution is available

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using external EF pattern and you use both providers. If your project connectionString placed/Not placed out of web.config please check that conString provider and be sure have a provider of EntityFramework element providers in web.config 
[EF config in Web.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an external form to connect to the database. Try to use the connectionStrings inside the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Other than not using configsource in the web.config, I know of no true solution to date. However, using config transformations seems to be an adequate workaround for me.

Example:

We have a re-write file that was referenced in the web.config using '*configSource*' (see A below). Due to scaffolding errors, I removed the entire node from web.config and added a transformation to Web.Release.config to insert it (see B below). I only needed this on prod, but presumably web.debug.config would work as well.

ps- if you right-click on web.release.config, you'll see an option to "Preview Transformation". It's very helpful.

A - Web.config (old)

```
<rewrite>  
    <rewriteMaps configSource="UrlRewriteMaps.config"></rewriteMaps>  <!-- configSource SCAFFOLDING ERROR HERE -->
</rewrite>
```

B - Web.Release.Config (new)

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rewriteMaps configSource="UrlRewriteMaps.config"></rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```